# Picking listbox display item by using keyboard control in TCL?

Tags: user-interface, listbox, tcl, bind, tk-toolkit

I'm currently using Tcl 8.4.11 version.
I'm wondering can i using the bind feature for the Listbox widget?

For example, i have a set of items will be displayed on the listbox...
Instead of using the mouse clicking to pick the item, i want to use the keyboard up and down key to pick the desired item after the first time clicking any item on the listbox.

Currently, i use below command for testing...

```
$listbox_a bindText  <ButtonPress-1>     "$listbox_a selection set"
```

This command allow me to use mouse for picking/selecting listbox item...
But subsequently, i want to use the keyboard up and down arrow to choose different item... is it difficult to implement this?

`<KeyPress>` & `<Key>` both also not working in my testing... :(

Please advise...Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listboxes have key bindings already as part of their class bindings. All you have to do is to add a binding for the `<KeyPress-Return>` event (usually written as `<Return>` for brevity) to the particular listbox that you want it for; the class bindings don't define anything for that, so it is free to use without worrying. (Remember, key events are only processed when the widget has the focus.)

You'll want to use the listbox's `curselection` method inside the binding to discover what is actually selected, of course. If you can upgrade to a *supported version* of Tk (8.5 or later) then you can use the `<<ListboxSelect>>` virtual event to track changes (it's generated following a whole range of real events that change what is selected) but that's not necessary here.

Comment: Thanks Bro...
I manage to achieve my objective finally...

but I am confuse with below 2 different types of tcl listbox widget
1) http://docs.activestate.com/activetcl/8.5/bwidget/ListBox.html

2) http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/listbox.htm#M1

The second one help to resolve all my problem.